# Set the headers using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that I read into a dataframe using the pandas API. 
I intend to set my own header instead of the default first row. (I also get rid of some of the rows.) How do I best achieve this?

I tried the following but this didn't work as expected:

```
header_row=['col1','col2','col3','col4', 'col1', 'col2'] # note the header has duplicate column values
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], names=header_row)
```

This gives following error -

```
File "third_party/py/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 187, in read_csv
File "third_party/py/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 160, in _read
File "third_party/py/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 628, in get_chunk
File "third_party/py/pandas/core/frame.py", line 302, in __init__
File "third_party/py/pandas/core/frame.py", line 388, in _init_dict
File "third_party/py/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1008, in form_blocks
File "third_party/py/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1036, in _simple_blockify
File "third_party/py/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1068, in _stack_dict
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I then tried settings the columns via

```
df.columns = header_row
```

But this error-ed out probably because of duplicate column values.

```
File "engines.pyx", line 101, in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc    
(third_party/py/pandas/src/engines.c:2498)
File "engines.pyx", line 107, in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc 
(third_party/py/pandas/src/engines.c:2447)
Exception: ('Index values are not unique', 'occurred at index entity')
```

I am using pandas 0.7.3 version.
From the documentation -

**names : array-like
    List of column names**

I am sure I am missing something simple here. Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas 0.7.3 does not support index duplicates. You need at least 0.8.0, between 0.8.0 and 0.8.1 several issues with duplicates in the index are fixed, so 0.8.1 (=most recent stable release) might be best. However even 0.8.1 is not an answer to your problem, because this version has an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1675) with duplicate column names (you can not display a dataframe with duplicate column names).

Comment: Thanks for the references. I revisited and got rid of the requirement for duplicate column values.